# How to convert RC4 to RC5 in angular2

Tags: angular

I used RC5 documentation for converting my RC4 code i followed the steps which shows in documentation.I update my npm and trying the npm start command but getting this issue please help.

[I attached my screeenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMcrk.png)

Comment: please share your ngmodule.ts? also check this- http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports:      [BrowserModule],
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

Comment: i just created a file named as app.module.ts

Comment: Try this - https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/08/13/updating-your-angular-2-app-from-rc4-to-rc5-a-practical-guide/